# Define custom behavior for meta tags in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

For example, there is a tag called startup:

`#+STARTUP: overview`

This tag has an effect of the org environment. Is there a way to modify or define these tags like startup?

Another example is `#+title` in the org buffer, any content after the title tag turns blue.

I looked in the docs but I cannot find where I can modify the behavior of these meta tags.

Comment: These are `keywords` and no,  you cannot modify their behavior, not without reprogramming Org mode.

Comment: What about creating new ones?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to be able to define a keyword for `#+category:` and have the text after it turn blue like the `#+title:`

Comment: There is *already* a keyword `#+category`. If you want to change the color of the text after it, then *that* is the question you should ask:  "I want the text of the value of the `#+category` keyword to be blue in color, like the value of the `#+title` keyword. How do I do that?".

Comment: No the question is correct. I wanted to know if i could create and edit keywords. That is still the case. What I gave you was one example of edited. regardless if there is a category keyword already, there is a long list of other keywords I wished to create and edit. If the answer is "I cannot create and edit keywords" then that is fine.

Comment: Well the answer is you cannot unless you modify Org mode to recognize them and to add whatever functionality you want them to have.